# Linq and anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

```
select new
{
 Selected = (cvf != null && cvf.Deleted==false)
}
```

The above statement proceeds to check cvf.Deleted even if cvf  is null. Then it throws an invalid object reference error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: invalid object reference, or null reference?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You don't by any chance have the != operator defined on the type of cvf? If you do, perhaps it isn't implemented correctly? I would suggest looking at the stack trace of the thrown exception.

Comment: There's also the chance that `cvf` is a property (and not a field) and throws there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something else going on since `&&` *will* [short-circuit evaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That said, try this instead:

```
select new
{
    Selected = cvf != null
        ? !cvf.Deleted
        : false
};
```

Comment: No matter how you look at `(cvf != null && cvf.Deleted == false)` that should always evaluate to either `true` or `false` and not ever throw an NRE.  I agree though, there is more to the story...